# using springboot with local elastic-search instance not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to use elasticSearch repository inside a spring boot application .
I have a **local** running instance of elastic search **5.5.2**
I've search for a while, tried so many combinations of the several sources but nothing yield a working solution , and right now I'm stuck with **error** :

> Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate'

what am i doing wrong ?

This is my **main** class

```
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("chapters.introduction.HelloWorld1");
            try
            {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                logger.info("caught an exception",e);
            }

        }
}
```

**config** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "hello")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"hello"})
public class config {

    @Bean
    public NodeBuilder nodeBuilder() {
        return new NodeBuilder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings =
                Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("http.enabled", "false") // 1
                        .put("path.data", "/home/nad/elasticsearch_data") // 2
                        .put("path.home", "/home/nad/Downloads/elasticsearch-5.5.2"); // 3



        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder()
                .local(true)
                .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
                .node()
                .client());
    }

}
```

my **build.gradle** file

```
group 'FirstWebServer'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '1.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '3.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.0.0.M6', ext: 'pom'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.18'

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

what is the proper way of configuration ? some examples shows **application.properties** configuration , some dont . 
What about **compatability** , some shows that only elasticsearch **2. *** or lower, some said that **5**

Its really confusing :(

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

To use Elasticsearch 5.x you need Spring Data release Kay (already released), which is only part of Spring Boot 2 (to be released soon). Right now your only option really is to use the latest Spring Boot 2 build and wait for a stable release.

Some people tried using Spring Data Kay with Spring boot 1.5, but ended up in dependency hell. Probably not worth the pain with Spring Boot 2 just around the corner.